# What is the difference between ++ and : in haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I don't get this--

```
Prelude> "hi"++"there"
"hithere"
Prelude> "hi":"there"

<interactive>:12:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char'
    Expected type: [[Char]]
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `"there"'
    In the expression: "hi" : "there"
Prelude>
```

Why doesn't that also return "hithere"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The types. Try this in GCHi:

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
Prelude. :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing the `:t` to me!

Comment: @Micah: The other really useful one is `:info`, which can give you lots of info about a type.

Answer (score 6):

I get it now. The first operator needs to be an element, not a list.

So if i did `'h':"ithere"` it would return `"hithere"`

Comment: Please don't post remarks to your question as an answer. You can add a comment instead.

Comment: If it was a true answer to your question, you should post it as an answer, that is right. But this post isn't an answer to your question; it's merely a comment.

Comment: In my opinion this post can be considered an answer.

Comment: The fact that the first operand is an element for `:` and a list for `++` *is* the difference, so I think this is an answer to the question too.

Comment: The "answer": "The first operator needs to be an element, not a list." Is not an answer to the question in the title, but an answer to the question in the post

Answer (score 4):

The operator `:` is one of the constructors for lists. So `"hello"` is `'h':'e':'l':'l':'o':[]`. You can imagine lists being defined like: (not real haskell syntax)

```
data List a = (:) a (List a) | []
```

`:` constructs a list by taking an element and a list. That's why the type is `a->[a]->[a]`.

`++` which concatenates lists is defined by using `:` as a primitive:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
```

Comment: Note that the only thing that prevents this to be real Haskell syntax is `[]`. You can indeed have infix data constructor (such as `:%` for `Data.Ratio`, they have to start by `:` like prefix data constructor have to start with uppercase) or even type constructor (`->` is one such infix type constructor)