# Higher-order function, parse error on input `|'

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, parse-error

Here is my code:

```
select_where_true :: (Double -> Bool) -> [Double] -> [Double]
select_where_true is_neg [a] = case [a] of
[] -> []
x:xs -> is_neg x 
             |(is_neg x) == False = []
             |(is_neg x) == True = x ++ (select_where_true is_neg xs)


is_neg :: Double -> Bool
is_neg x = x < 0
```

And here is the error message:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:5:18: parse error on input `|'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Anyone likes to tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks for anyone who can good me some advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to re-implement `takeWhile` (or possibly a bugged `filter`), so we could simply set

```
select_where_true :: (Double -> Bool) -> [Double] -> [Double]
select_where_true = takeWhile
```

But anyway, there are several problems with your code.

- The syntax error you got is because you're using the wrong syntax for guards in a `case`. The correct syntax is

  ```
  case ... of
      pattern | guard -> ...
              | ...   -> ...
  ```
- Fixing that reveals a type error in your code. You're trying to use `++` to prepend an *element* to a list, but `++` concatenates two *lists*. To prepend an element, use `:` instead. See: [What is the difference between ++ and : in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569650/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-haskell)
- With that fixed, the code compiles, but there is a bug: it fails on the empty list, or on lists with
  more than one element:

  ```
  > select_where_true is_neg []
  *** Exception: S.hs:(2,1)-(5,66): Non-exhaustive patterns in function select_where_true

  > select_where_true is_neg [1,2]
  *** Exception: S.hs:(2,1)-(5,66): Non-exhaustive patterns in function select_where_true
  ```

  This is because you're unintentionally doing pattern matching here:

  ```
  select_where_true is_neg [a] = ...
                           ^^^
  ```

  This is a pattern which only matches lists with exactly one element. To match any list, simply
  get rid of the brackets. You'll have to get rid of the brackets in `case [a] of ...` as well.

Fixing all of these problems, we end up with

```
select_where_true :: (Double -> Bool) -> [Double] -> [Double]
select_where_true is_neg a = case a of
    [] -> []
    x:xs | (is_neg x) == False -> []
         | (is_neg x) == True  -> x : (select_where_true is_neg xs)
```

Finally, some style suggestions:

- Most of the parentheses are unnecessary. Function application has higher precedence than any operator.
- Never write `expr == True` or `expr == False`. Use `expr` or `not expr` instead.
- If the guards cover all cases, you can replace the last one with `otherwise`.
- A case expression with guards like this is somewhat awkward. It's often easier to write multiple
  equations instead:

  ```
  select_where_true :: (Double -> Bool) -> [Double] -> [Double]
  select_where_true is_neg [] = []
  select_where_true is_neg (x:xs)
    | is_neg x  = x : select_where_true is_neg xs
    | otherwise = []
  ```

Comment: Thx u so much, i have followed what u said and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Guards don't go there. Use a case statement instead. as in `case isNeg x of`

Answer (score 1):

you can write it like this:

```
select_where_true :: (Double -> Bool) -> [Double] -> [Double]
select_where_true is_neg [a] = case [a] of
  []                -> []
  (x:xs) | is_neg x -> x ++ (select_where_true is_neg xs)
  oterwise          -> []
```

coincidentally, the first case is impossible; and in second `(x:xs)=[a]` means `x=a, xs=[]`. Perhaps you meant `select_where_true is_neg a = case a of ...`, without the brackets.